# How to make moving canvas objects with images in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

So I'm working on a project where I have a canvas filled with moving balls. Its an extension/inspired by this codepen project : https://codepen.io/zetyler/pen/LergVR .

It essentially runs with the same physics in place as the codepen, but now I'm trying to draw the moving and colliding balls with images instead of random colors.

The original draw() method looks like this :

```
var pen = canvas.getContext('2d');
const W = canvas.width;
const H = canvas.height;

var numBalls = 30;
var grav = [0,-0.1];

function Ball(x,y,dx,dy,r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
    this.r = r;
    this.color = 'hsl('+(Math.random()*360)+',90%,50%)';
    
    this.draw = function() {
        pen.fillStyle = this.color;
        pen.beginPath();
        pen.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,2*Math.PI);
        pen.fill();
    }
```

I'm refactoring the draw method to try and work with an image instead of a random color fill, and so far I can't even get an image to show up. Currently my draw method looks like this:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;

let numBalls = 1;
let grav = [0,-0.1];

//try feeding the ball function an object
//and destructuring the inputs
class Ball {

    constructor (x, y, dx, dy, r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
        this.r = r;
        //probably won't need this
        //this.color = 'hsl(' + (Math.random() * 360) + ', 90%, 50%)';
    }

    draw() {
        var thumbImg = document.createElement('img');

        thumbImg.src = './svgs/javascriptIcon.svg';
        thumbImg.onload = function() {
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(25, 25, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            context.closePath();
            context.clip();

            context.drawImage(thumbImg, 0, 0, 50, 50);

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(0, 0, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            context.clip();
            context.closePath();
            context.restore();
        };
    }
```

It's been so long since I've used the html canvas. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I thought I would at least be able to get the image to show up, but no such luck.

Thanks for checking it out! Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using `ctx.clip`,
but if you just want to replace the coloured balls with images try this in your draw method

```
 this.draw = function() {
        // make sure the img is loaded
        //pen.fillStyle = this.color;
        pen.beginPath();
        pen.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,2*Math.PI);
        pen.drawImage(img,this.x, this.y,this.r, this.r)
        pen.fill();
    }
```

after that play with IMG x and y positions for example `pen.drawImage(img,this.x + somefactor, this.y - somefactor,this.r + somefactor, this.r + somefatcor)`
just to make sure that img is perfectly cover the coloured ball so it behavies just like it

Comment: I went ahead and tried to implement what you recommended as you can see here:

```draw() {

        var thumbImg = document.createElement('img');

        thumbImg.src = './svgs/images.jpg';
        thumbImg.onload = function() {
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.drawImage(thumbImg, this.x, this.y, this.r, this.r)
            context.fill();

        };
    }
```

Still, nothing is showing up in the canvas. I even changed the image src to a jpeg in case it just didnt want svgs

Comment: try to load the image outside the ball class and pass it as an  argument, then call the animate  function(where you used `requestAnimationFrame`) after the image loads

Comment: I have done that now and still am not seeing anything. I'm misunderstanding/misremembering something somewhere in my Ball class so I'm going to rewrite it. For you and anyone else, I'll post back when I get it up and running. Thanks for the help!